# Transaction management in Spring: Does support come from Spring or container?

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am trying to understand the transaction management in Spring, and I have got some doubts.

I read a bit about transaction management in `EJB world`, which can be `CMT` or `BMT`. For `CMT`, as per the documentation, it is `Application server` (e.g. JBOSS) which manages the transaction.

Now, coming to Spring transaction management, and considering using `Web container` only (`Apache Tomcat`), how does this work?

Does Spring have its own transaction management with capability of handling `local transaction` and `global transaction` (which works with 2 phase commit). Do the actual support need to come by the underlying `container` (in this case Apache tomcat) or support from framework is sufficient?

I am not clear how all these pieces fit together.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring doesn't include any kind of transaction capability of its own, it only provides ways to connect to transaction functionality provided by the container or by standalone libraries.

If you run your application on Tomcat and don't provide any transaction manager libraries like bitronix, then you get only local jdbc transactions provided by the servlet container.

When you read the bullet points at https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html notice it says spring is providing abstractions, that means it is providing access through its own apis and using aop to make transactions nonintrusive, but not providing any implementation of transactional functionality. It's facilitating gluing things together, which is the main thing spring does.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am getting more confused than ever.  There is spring-tx module in Spring; so is this just a wrapper on top of actual "provider" who does the transaction management. This is something which makes things confusion. If I understood Spring framework doesn't have any transaction capability of its own, so does it mean to "plug-in" other providers and using spring-tx module which acts as wrapper? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Thanks again for your response, makes sense.